# Python library to plot coordinates on a map given angle and speed of object

Tags: python

I want to plot (on a coordinate map) the path a ship has traveled. I have time series data with angle and velocity... something like

1s, 10 mph, 4 degrees

2s, 14 mph, -3 degrees

3s, 9 mph, 2 degrees

....

Is there a python library available that will help me plot this on an XY coordinate grid?

This question is similar... and a good start.
[update coordinates based on angle and speed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7217478/update-coordinates-based-on-angle-and-speed)

Ultimately, I want a library like
[x,y] = function(velocity, angle, prevX, prevY)

and then I want to plot all the x,y points. Does a library exist like that?

So far I have this...

```
import numpy as np
import math

def calc_xy(angle, speed):

    # Starting variables
    curx = 0
    cury = 0
    curang = math.radians(0)

    x = np.empty(len(angle))
    y = np.empty(len(angle))

    for z in range(len(angle)):

        x[z], y[z], curang = calc_xy_interior(angle[z], speed[z], curx, cury, curang)
        curx = x[z]
        cury = y[z]

    return x, y

def calc_xy_interior(angle, speed, curx, cury, curang):


    # Calculate distance travelled in meters
    angle_radians = math.radians(angle) + curang
    xtravel = 0.277778 * speed * math.cos(angle_radians)
    ytravel = 0.277778 * speed * math.sin(angle_radians)

    x = curx + xtravel
    y = cury + ytravel

    return x, y, angle_radians
```

Comment: I don't know of an existing library for this and I doubt there is one for such a specific problem (who knows, though...), but `numpy` and a bit of work should get you there pretty quickly as far as the computation is concerned and `matplotlib` will do for the plotting. How experienced are you with python? Did you know about those? Do you need help with them and would they be an acceptable solution or do you really need the library?

Comment: Also, are you aware of the problems associated with computing a position from a velocity known only at discrete points in time?

Comment: user35915.... having a library would just be nice instead of having to create this myself.... although as you can see above, I'm starting to.

I recognize that this method isn't perfect but this is the best I can do

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so in Python there's a rule: avoid `for` loops wherever possible. They're really slow. `numpy` makes this pretty easy by allowing you to do operations on entire arrays with its universal functions and broadcasting. This is usually a good choice if your arrays consume small fractions of the memory you have available.

Then you have to worry about the memory layout of your arrays. `numpy` uses row-major layout by default. Since in your problem we can treat the x and y dimensions in bulk, a good shape for the arrays therefore is `(2, N)`, where `N` is the number of points.

The way I would go about your problem then is as follows:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np


def cal_vel(angles, speeds):
    vel = np.empty((2, len(angles)))
    vel[0, :] = speeds*np.cos(angles)
    vel[1, :] = speeds*np.sin(angles)
    return vel


def calc_x(vel, delta_t, x_0):
    x = np.zeros((2, len(delta_t)+1)) + x_0
    x[:, 1:] = np.cumsum(delta_t*vel, axis=1)
    return x


N = 10
times = np.linspace(1, 100, num=N)
angles = 2*np.pi*np.random.random(N)
speeds = np.random.random(N)
delta_t = np.empty(N)
delta_t[0] = times[0]
delta_t[1:] = times[1:] - times[:-1]
x_0 = np.array([[0], [0]])

x = calc_x(cal_vel(angles, speeds), delta_t, x_0)
print(x)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(x[0, :], x[1, :])
plt.show()
```

I realize that this might be a bit much if you're unfamiliar with `numpy`, just ask if you need clarification.

---

Oh and btw. this is a very crude way of integrating a trajectory, in case you are not aware. If you do not sample your velocity frequently enough (in time) and/or do this for a long time you will predict your ship to be very far away from where it actually is.

Comment: hmmmm... this does not give the results that I was looking for. I'm recording data once a second. Perhaps its because of the issue you mentioned before

Comment: There might be a bug in it :-). Can you be more specific as to what doesn't meet your expectations?

Comment: Remember to convert your angles to radians before using the functions. And also of course to convert your times and speeds to the units you want to use.

Comment: Oh wait, I think I see a problem: what are your angles? Are they relative to the last direction your ship was traveling in? Or are they relative to the x-axis?